# Setup proxy config for emacs using PAC script

Tags: emacs, proxy

I am trying to access Gmail using gnus in emacs for windows behind a corporate firewall. I connect to the internet using a Proxy Auto-Config script.

Is there a way that I can directly use the URL to the PAC script in emacs?

something like

```
(setq url-proxy-pac "http://mypacscript.pac")
```

I tried to figure out the proxy from the script and plugged it into emacs using the following (with modified values as per the PAC script)

```
(setq url-proxy-services
    '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10.*\\)")
    ("http" . "proxy.com:8080")
    ("https" . "proxy.com:8080")))
```

With that proxy, I can connect to the internet using my browser but I can't connect Gmail from emacs gnus. And, I am able to connect to Gmail from emacs at home network without a proxy. I am not sure what I am missing.